# MySQL next previous record issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my script

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    $id = 1;
}

    $random = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY RAND()");
    $row = $random->fetch();

    $stmt_1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $stmt_1->bindValue(1,$id);
    $stmt_1->execute();
    $stmt_1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $stmt_1->fetch();
    $id = $row['id'];

    $stmt_1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DSC LIMIT 1");
    $stmt_1->bindValue(1,$id);
    $stmt_1->execute();
    $stmt_1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $stmt_1->fetch();
    $id = $row['id'];

    ?>
```

But I have a problem with it. For example i have 4 records in database :

```
ID String
1  Test-1
2  Test-2
3  Test-3
4  Test-4
```

the query works fine it gives me the next record but not the id which i put like if i put id=1 returns id 2 or id=2 returns info for id 3  and the result is not accurate. So my question is what should I do id to return correct result not +1. I know it starts to count from 0 and i want to fix that in my script i want to make it to start from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
   $id = 1;
```

by

```
   $id = 0;
```

or replace this

```
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > ?
```

by

```
   SELECT * FROM records WHERE id >= ?
                                   ^--//-will look for id equal to 1 or bigger
```

Comment: Thank you very much now it's working but my hyperlink 
<a href="./index.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">Next</a> Cant work now...

Comment: in your hyper link what you want id to be ? same id or id+1 ?

Comment: which solution it solved yours ? the first or second ? better use  second solution.if you use the id in hyperlink

Comment: With my old code before you helped me this hyperlink was changing the id +1 now it can't. this hyperlink is for the next record it gets id from : $id = $row['id']; - $stmt_1 so it can go id+1.

Comment: Yep i will use second one.

Comment: be sure to use in second query this also `WHERE id <= ?`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you change your query to

**EDIT:** Query will not work as records are deleted.

```
$stmt_1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = ?");
$stmt_1->bindValue(1,$id +1);
$stmt_1->execute();
```

So you will get the record with the next highest id.

Just a hint to optimize your query. 
One further question do you use auto_increment in your table definition. If you do so, you shold keep in mind that this mysql-sequence starts by one to calculate the primary key

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes ID is A_I but i don't think that with $stmt_1->bindValue(1,$id +1); i will get the next possible reccord what if next id is deleted?